# Place 2 titles in one row?

Tags: html, text, row

hey guys can you help me place this 2 texts in same row without changing color and size of text ?

```
<blockquote><p style="color:red; font-size:45px"> Company </p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p align="right" style="color:white; font-size:35px">telephone number </p></blockquote>
```

Comment: You are **explicitly** putting the text on different lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use `<ul>` and `<li>` tags and use css `display:inline;` to get them both to be in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

set `blockquote` to `display: inline-block` to make them inline:

```
blockquote{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/epmakdhr/)

or you could but them in the same `blockquote` and set the `p` to `inline` or `inline-block`:

**HTML**

```
<blockquote><p style="color:red; font-size:45px"> Company </p><p align="right" style="color:white; font-size:35px">telephone number </p></blockquote>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
   display: inline;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/epmakdhr/2/)

**UPDATE**

you would just add this into your CSS file (best option):

```
blockquote{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

or if your CSS is on the same page (not as good an option):

```
<style>
   blockquote{
      display: inline-block;
   }
</style>
```

or if you're insistent on inline styles (worst option) it would be written like this:

```
<blockquote style="display: inline-block;"><p style="color:red; font-size:45px"> Company </p></blockquote>
<blockquote style="display: inline-block;"><p align="right" style="color:white; font-size:35px">telephone number </p></blockquote>
```

Comment: sry for asking you about this but could you wrote it for me how it suppost to look like? coz i am kinda new in html :) thx )